# How to get sub property of array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with getting sub property of an array. Here is the snippet:

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this.menus = this.navService.defaultMenu;
     console.log(this.getMenusItem());
     this.registerChangeInProjects();
 }
```

Above code gives me:

[image]

I need to get that sub elements from the main array. Here is view snippet:

```
<div class="module-buttons" *ngFor="let item of getMenusItem().sub">
                    <div *hasAnyAuthority="item.roles" class="btn-item" routerLinkActive="active"
                        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
                        <a
                            routerLink="{{ item.state }}">{{ 'khanbankCpmsApp.' + item.name + '.home.title' | translate }}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

What  am i droing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the result from getMenusItem() is actually an array so you would have to do something like:

```
let item of getMenusItem()[0].sub
```

Comment: @batgerel.e all good - please mark as correct if you're happy with the answer :-)